# Ralink Wifi works on LiveUSB OS but not when installed

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, live-usb, ralink

I have just inherited a HP Pavillion with Ralink Wifi - it worked as good as gold on 16.04 LiveUSB OS but when installed and rebooted no wifi.

The wifi lists as device not ready in network manager

`iwconfig` says:

```
 root@obadiah:~# iwconfig 
 enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

 lo        no wireless extensions.

 wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

And `lshw -C network` says:

```
root@obadiah:~# lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 03
       serial: 40:61:86:c0:b3:4f
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw ip=192.168.1.194 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:d800(size=256) memory:fbdff000-fbdfffff memory:faffc000-faffffff memory:fbdc0000-fbddffff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3092 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:26:82:65:4d:3a
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-36-generic firmware=0.34 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:fbff0000-fbffffff
```

Any ideas on how to make this work... I have looked at blacklists and a few forum posts but not much seems to be recent to Ubuntu 16.04

Results from `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Results from: `lsmod | grep wmi`:

```
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  41 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
```

Results from `dmesg | grep rt2`
[

```
 17.809034] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3071, rev 0213 detected
[   17.812471] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0008 detected
[   17.818054] rt2800pci 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
[   24.679600] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2860.bin'
[   24.806537] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.34
[  585.750510] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1236.456222] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1236.920174] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1237.384119] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1237.856065] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1238.323995] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1238.787957] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1239.255869] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1239.719811] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1240.187757] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1240.655665] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1241.463595] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 1241.983535] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2442.352839] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2442.820831] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2443.284792] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2443.752764] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2444.220759] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2444.972677] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2445.436726] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2446.188669] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2446.996632] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2447.512567] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 2977.880219] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3045.314180] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3045.782146] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3046.246133] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3047.002036] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3047.753977] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3048.217925] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3048.969856] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3049.773782] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3050.289718] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 3151.300331] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[ 4179.483924] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 6594.528055] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
[ 6957.819877] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
```

Comment: DISABLED usually means that the switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless radio. Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep wmi` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Edited into the question above

Comment: May we also see: `dmesg | greo rt2` ?

Comment: Edited into the question above